# Using Linux as a replacement for a female-female USB adapter?

Tags: linux, usb

I'm trying to access a phone I own with a broken touch screen.

Long story short, I want to use OTG to connect a USB mouse to the phone, but I don't own an OTG/USB-USB connector. All I have is a Linux PC.

Is Linux capable of capturing raw data from a USB port and forwarding it as-is to another port, thus creating a software powered female to female USB adapter?

Comment: Female to Female USB adapters are inexpensive and readily available.  I keep spares in my electronics box. Why not just use an adapter?

Comment: @John to learn Linux and because I'm stubborn of course

Comment: I am using Linux here to post and there are many things to learn, but it seems less useful to me to make a readily available adapter using a computer. Just my own thoughts.

Comment: Such functionality doesn’t exist. Your best bet is to get a cheap USB A (female) to USB C (male) connector assuming your phone connects with USB C.

Comment: My understanding is that with Linux you can read and write raw bytes to/from USB devices. I find it weird that no one has asked this question before. Do you know why this functionality doesn't exist/isn't implemented yet?

Comment: Your project is learning programming, and it is not a learning Linux idea so far as I can see.

Answer (score 3):

USB OTG requires the adaptor to bridge a pin in order to signal it is an OTG device adaptor and expects the phone to act as a host rather than a normal charger or a cable connected to a computer.

You need that adaptor, you can't just connect two USB ports together and hope they work. Without that adaptor you phone will forever be expecting a computer to ask it questions, as it it is locked into being a client, rather than the phone being the one asking the questions, i.e. a host.

From [Electrical Engineering: ML06 Micro To Micro USB wiring](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/430300/289610)

> [image]
>
> Note the yellow Sense/ID line. This pin is almost always **unconnected** in a standard micro-USB cable. Also there is usually **no wire connected to it**. So I would be surprised if you can even convert a standard micro-USB to a micro-USB-OTG connector. The connection isn't there and it is not accessible. Standard micro USB cables don't need this connection so it isn't included.

Without that wire your phone will never recognise it is a host USB device, and so will never accept bytes as if it is the host. That host - client relationship is needed for a mouse to work on the phone, and is needed for the computer to act as some kind of client emulating a mouse.

Once you have the correct adaptor you might as well just plug a mouse into it rather than a computer.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer